# Does anyone have an example of unit testing a component inside a module in angular 2.0?

Tags: unit-testing, angular

I'm having trouble understanding the proper way to test my components that belong inside a module. If ComponentA belongs to ModuleA what's the proper way to configure the testModule?

```
 TestBed.configureTestingModule({imports:[ModuleA]})
```

gives me errors like  Unexpected value 'undefined' declared by the module 'ModuleA'. My guess is I'm getting into some bad circular dependencies by doing that.

```
  TestBed.configureTestingModule({declarations: [ComponentA]})
```

gives me errors like Type ComponentA is part of the declarations of 2 modules: DynamicTestModule and ModuleA!

Is one of these the right strategy or is there a 3rd path I'm missing here?

Comment: _Unexpected value 'undefined' declared by the module 'ModuleA'_. I've had similar problems related to using barrels. [Maybe related issue](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/1831).

Comment: I'd like to make sure that's the right path before I try to get into that rabbit hole...

Comment: There's nothing wrong with importing the module. The problem I faced was strictly related to webpack and how it handles barrels. If you are using webpack and barrels, then you may be facing the same problem. As far as your second attempt at declaring the component, that error is correct as the TestBed configures a module, but your module also declares the component. if you declare the component in the TestBed, dont import the module. You can see if it works. But personally I would try to figure out the problem with the barrel if you are using it.

Comment: I've spent a day and a half just to find out that ordering of exports in my barrel was causing the problem. Personally, I am starting the migrate away from using barrels. The pains of dealing with then outweighs the benefits. Maybe until whatever bug related to this issue is fixed

Comment: I haven't been using barrels, but I bet it's a similar ordering issue somewhere.